# Log to Azure file

Tags: c#, azure, webclient

How can I create and write to a log file on Azure?

In a web app, not running in Azure, I need to log to a text file. I figure writing to one on Azure should work.

So what/where on Azure would I write to? What credentials do I use and how do I open a web connection to it?

Once I have that, writing and closing the stream are trivial.

In C#

**And big constraint** - I can't add any libraries. So I have the .NET runtime. But I can't add any of the Azure Blob libraries. I have to use the .NET runtime web client, etc. classes.

Comment: You can save data in blob storage.

Comment: Does it need to be file? Did you consider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?

Comment: @GauravMantri Life is easier if it's a file. But a BLOB would work - can you answer with details on that?

Comment: @PeterBons The app is not an Azure app so writing to insights doesn't make sense I think as there is no Azure Web app to have the insights.

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't make sense to use App Insights. You can use it for anything, not just Azure apps, not even just .NET apps. But if you want files [look at append blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-append-blobs)

Comment: Azure storage has a REST api, you don't need to use the client libraries but of course it is much simpler to do so.

Comment: @DavidThielen I use Application Insights for on-premises web apps and desktop apps. It is not bound to azure workloads only.

Comment: Where does the big constraint come from? Libs are there to make life easier. Lots of them are developed by Microsoft itself if it is about trust and active development.

Comment: @PeterBons I am using this in QuantConnect and they do not allow any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: "Where does the big constraint come from?"
What does it matter...? He's not asking to remove the constraints, so why bother going down that road?